Osmium subprocess call
How do I correctly format a subprocess call to osmium via Jupyter Notebook please?
#- osmium extract -p paris-polygon.poly france.pbf -o paris.pbf
sp = subprocess.check_call(['/Users/.../miniconda3/envs/geo3D_distV2/bin/osmium extract', \
                            '-p', '/data/western-cape.poly', \
                            '/data/south-africa-latest.osm.pbf --input-format/pbf', \
                            '-o', '/data/wc.pbf --output-format/pbf'], shell=True)

I want to extract a region (-o', '/data/wc.pbf) from a larger file (/data/south-africa-latest.osm.pbf',) based on a polygon (-p', '/data/western-cape.poly).
From the documentation:

Which format a file has is usually autodetected from the file name suffix. If  this  doesn’t work, either because you are reading from
STDIN or writing to STDOUT, or because you have an unusual file name,
you have to set the format manually. You can  also set the format
manually if you want to specify special format options.
Most  osmium  commands support the --input-format/-F and --output-format/-f options to set the format.  They take a comma-separated list of  arguments,  the  first  is  the  format,
further arguments set additional options.

I do not know how to translate those words into code.
How do I format the subprocess call correctly please?
